# Create a single entity for each of existing entity using queue lead to many duplications

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE task queue in a common situation, i.e. create a single Entity for each `User` entity,
In each task(url based), i did:

1. Iterator with a fix number of `User` entity per time(say, 500).
2. Create one Entity for each user and batch save it(async).
3. Enqueue next task with end cursor as the start of next iteration, until no `User` to iterate.

This seem work nice but i found i got many duplicated Entities there, say, i have 10k users but turn out there are 20k+ other entities created.

My question is why the so many duplicated entities and any way to prevent?

Thanks

Comment: can we see some code please

Comment: your task might be failing and then retrying, causing duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to solve if you can show the code.
However the apparent reason may be that the task is failing for some reason (may be memory error or something like this). so what you can do is to add a flag in your User model that an entity has been created for this particular User or you can check whether an entity occurs for this use before creating a new one. In this way even if your task fails it will not make entity for that user again.

Comment: Yes that can well explain why i got right result sometime but wrong in  other time, but how about create a batch of entities from json data without duplication, while each json correspond to one entity?